# how to pass custom validation message to cviebrock/image-validator in laravel?

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-validation

I am using [cviebrock](https://github.com/cviebrock/image-validator) for validating image size in laravel. And thats working fine. But I want to customize the error message.

I created an array of message

```
 $messages = array(
        'image-size'    => 'My custome message.',
    );
```

and passed to

```
$validation = Validator::make(array($file => $fileObj), array($file  => $rules), $messages);
```

But thats not working.

-Thanks
Arun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong name, it should be with an underline, like

```
$messages = array(
    'image_size'    => 'My custome message.',
);
```