# Laravel validation message for max size is incorrect

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

I'm currently facing this issue where I want to use the `max` key when I upload a file. But then it returns a different message. The `max` key returns the `uploaded` message instead of the `max` message. I know I can use the `uploaded` key but this key is for validation when the file was not successfully uploaded. [[Other reference]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52756480/custom-validation-message-for-image-size-rule-in-laravel).

**Code**

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'image' => 'required|max:2048|file|mimetypes:image/jpg,image/jpeg,image/png'
    ];
}

public function messages()
{
    return [
        'image.max' => 'The image file size must not be greater than 2Mb.'
    ];
}
```

**Expected**

> The image file size must not be greater than 2Mb.'

**Result**

> The image failed to upload.

Comment: ``image.max`` will only return if the uploaded file size is greater than 2MB not for other wise any other reason! You need to dig deeper and find out why upload is unsuccessful !

Comment: Maybe you have to update `upload_max_filesize` , as @OMiShah said the error is not related to your max validation

Comment: the server is completely ditching the body after it hits a certain size, so to PHP there is no file uploaded since it was outside the POST max size or upload max size, etc etc

Comment: I am uploading a 2.3Mb file so I don't think it has to do with my configuration.